# Fatal: module nfs not found

Tags: nfs, modprobe, chrubuntu

I am setting up a new NFS client on a LAN that has a working NFS server (Ubuntu 12.04) running nfs4. The other clients all work as expected.

On this new client I'm running ChrUbuntu with kernel 3.4.0 (Kubuntu 12.04) on an Acer Chromebook. I installed nfs-common. However, the mount command returns the error `mount.nfs4 no such device`. And `# modprobe nfs` returns `Fatal: module nfs not found`. Google didn't offer me any solutions.

The mount command is like:

```
sudo mount -t nfs4 -o _netdev,noatime,auto,rw myserver:/home/user/shared /home/user/mountpoint
```

The modprobe command is:

```
sudo modprobe nfs
```

And nfs-common is the latest version from this release's repo: 1:1.2.5-3ubuntu3.1

Comment: What mount command? What are your nfs settings? Have you started the nfs service?

Comment: Did you tried restarting?

Comment: @terdon: the specific mount command doesn't matter because the real problem is that `# modprobe nfs` returns `Fatal: module nfs not found`. I can't start nfs if the kernel module isn't found.

Comment: @Braiam - Yes, I restarted after installing nfs-common.

Comment: It might matter for the no such device error. Also, is this on the host or on the client? And _have you activated the service_? Run ` sudo service nfs-kernel-server status` on the host. Basically, just edit your question and tell us what you have installed on the host, and what on the client to get this to work.

Comment: There you go, did you also install `nfs-kernel-server` on the server?

Comment: @terdon: see if the updated question gives all the info you need. Thanks!

Comment: OK, first make sure that the server is reachable by name, try using the IP instead. What is the output of `sudo service nfs-common status` on the client? Admittedly though, the lack of the module is worrying. Also, you might be hitting [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/659084) though it is for an older kernel.

Comment: @terdon - I am using the IP address in the mount command. It is exactly the same mount command that works on all the other clients. And there is no such service as nfs-common on any client (even the working clients).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`modprobe` is looking in `/lib/modules` to know whether a module is present. So you should check first if the current version of your running kernel has `nfs` module:

```
ls -l /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/fs
```

if you don't see `nfs` folder, it means the `nfs` module is not compiled for your running kernel. You can recompile kernel to make it use `nfs` module. However, you should upgrade your kernel first:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo init 6
```

Comment: The kernel is already the latest. The `nfs` folder ***is*** missing. Given that this is ChrUbuntu, there is no way I am going to recompile the kernel. So I guess I am out of luck. But your answer seems to be the most correct one...